# Count operation on multiple condition using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the schema with sample data of table es_preadmission

```
  admno  |pre_gender|pre_class| pre_scat_id |bpl |sgc |handi|ser_cat
---------|----------|---------|-------------|----|----|-----|--------
    1    |Male      |1        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |1
    2    |Male      |1        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |1
    3    |Male      |1        |GEN          |bpl |no  |no   |1
    4    |Female    |2        |GEN          |no  |sgc |no   |1
    5    |Male      |1        |SC           |no  |no  |no   |1
    6    |Female    |1        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |1
    7    |Female    |2        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |5
    8    |Male      |2        |GEN          |bpl |no  |no   |1
    9    |Male      |2        |ST           |no  |no  |no   |1
    10   |Male      |1        |OBC          |no  |no  |no   |3
    11   |Female    |1        |ST           |no  |no  |no   |5
    12   |Male      |2        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |1
    13   |Male      |2        |SC           |no  |no  |PH   |1
    14   |Female    |2        |SC           |bpl |no  |no   |1
    15   |Female    |1        |GEN          |no  |no  |no   |2
```

**I am trying to get the number of male and female students from each categories (GEN, SC,ST,OBC), bpl, sgc, handi,ser_cat class wise. Example

```
        1       2 
      M   F   M   F
GEN   20  9   25  10
SC    5   2   9   4
ST    0   3   0   0
OBC   1   2   1   0
PH    0   0   1   0
BPL   2   3   7   2
```

**
Now to achive the above numbers I am trying something like this -

```
SELECT pre_scat_id AS cat, pre_gender, COUNT(admno)
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE pre_scat_id IN ('GEN','SC','ST','OBC')
GROUP BY pre_scat_id, pre_gender
UNION ALL
SELECT pre_handi AS cat, pre_gender, COUNT(admno)
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE pre_handi = 'Yes' OR pre_handi = 'No'
GROUP BY pre_handi, pre_gender
UNION ALL
SELECT pre_bpl AS cat, pre_gender, COUNT(admno)
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE pre_bpl = 'Yes' OR pre_bpl ='No'
GROUP BY pre_bpl, pre_gender;
```

But I am not getting desired output. Below output is drawn on actual database based on above query.

```
cat|pre_gender|COUNT(admno)
GEN| Female   |216
GEN| Male     |371
OBC| Female   |30
OBC| Male     |50
SC | Female   |36
SC | Male     |65
ST | Male     |9
No | Female   |281
No | Male     |495
PH | Male     |1
No | Female   |268
No | Male     |467
bpl| Female   |13
bpl| Male     |25
```

Need help how to get the output class wise

Comment: If you just need class added to what you have, you should be able to add it to the select list and group by of each query used to build the final output. It might be easier to understand what you want as output if you could lay it out in table format.

Comment: @mdatwood Kindly see the edited Post I updated the output required in table format. Well in between these data will be used in report generation using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate different CASEs, e.g. for the first SELECT:

```
SELECT pre_scat_id AS cat
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN pre_gender = 'Male'   AND pre_class = 1 THEN 1 END) AS M1
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN pre_gender = 'Female' AND pre_class = 1 THEN 1 END) AS F1
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN pre_gender = 'Male'   AND pre_class = 2 THEN 1 END) AS M2
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN pre_gender = 'Female' AND pre_class = 2 THEN 1 END) AS F2
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE pre_scat_id IN ('GEN','SC','ST','OBC')
GROUP BY pre_scat_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much your small guidance shown me a the way to get my goal